# Biopython translate() error

Tags: python, biopython

I have a file that looks as so:

```
Type    Variant_class   ACC_NUM dbsnp   genomic_coordinates_hg18    genomic_coordinates_hg19    HGVS_cdna   HGVS_protein    gene    disease sequence_context_hg18   sequence_context_hg19   codon_change    codon_number    intron_number   site    location    location_reference_point    author  journal vol page    year    pmid    entrezid    sift_score  sift_prediction mutpred_score
1   DM  CM920001    rs1800433   null    chr12:9232351:- NM_000014.4 NP_000005.2:p.C972Y A2M Chronicobstructivepulmonarydisease  null    CACAAAATCTTCTCCAGATGCCCTATGGCT[G/A]TGGAGAGCAGAATATGGTCCTCTTTGCTCC   TGT TAT 972 null    null    2   null    Poller  HUMGENET    88  313 1992    1370808 2   0   DAMAGING    0.594315245478036
1   DM  CM004784    rs74315453  null    chr22:43089410:-    NM_017436.4 NP_059132.1:p.M183K A4GALT  Pksynthasedeficiency(pphenotype)    null    TGCTCTCCGACGCCTCCAGGATCGCACTCA[T/A]GTGGAAGTTCGGCGGCATCTACCTGGACAC   ATG AAG 183 null    null    2   null    Steffensen  JBC 275 16723   2000    10747952    53947   0   DAMAGING    0.787878787878788
```

I want to translate the information from column 13 and 14 to their corresponding amino acids. Here is the script that I've generated:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna

InFile = open("disease_mut_splitfinal.txt", 'rU')

InFile.readline()
OriginalSeq_list = []
MutSeq_list = []

import csv
with open("disease_mut_splitfinal.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter= "\t")
    for row in reader: 
        OriginalSeq = row['codon_change']
        MutSeq = row['codon_number']
        region = row["genomic_coordinates_hg19"]
        gene = row["gene"]
        OriginalSeq_list.append(OriginalSeq)
        MutSeq_list.append(MutSeq)

OutputFileName = "Translated.txt"
OutputFile = open(OutputFileName, 'w')
OutputFile.write(''+region+'\t'+gene+'\n')


for i in range(0, len(OriginalSeq_list)):
    OrigSeq = OriginalSeq_list[i]
    MutSEQ = MutSeq_list[i]
    print OrigSeq
    translated_original = OrigSeq.translate()
    translated_mut= MutSEQ.translate()

    OutputFile.write("\n" + OriginalSeq_list[i]+ "\t" + str(translated_original) + "\t" +MutSeq_list[i] + "\t" + str(translated_mut)+ "\n")
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: translate expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

I'm kind of at a loss for what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd8chtacj3glb8d/disease_mut_splitfinal.txt?dl=0

(File should still be downloadable even if you don't have a dropbox)

Comment: Where does `output` come from? Also where are you using biopython? You also seem to be opening the files twice for no reason

Comment: Yes, that's true. I don't need to write to the file twice. I also fixed my output as well.

Comment: Are you really only wanting the last value of region?

Comment: No I do not, but I'm failing to get any sort of output at this time. I just want to get my translate to work so I can fix my code.

Comment: If you add a link to the actual file it will help, there seems to be quite a few problems in your code

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. My output file is all messed up

Comment: I wanted my "region" and "gene" to be on the same line as my translated output

Comment: If you can add a link to the actual file I will have a look at it

Comment: @Padriac I've attached a link to my file. Thank you so much for your help. I've just recently started working in a computational lab and it's my first time learning to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the string method "translate" instead of the biopython seq object method translate, which is what I assume you want to do.  You need to convert the string into a seq object and then translate that.  Try

```
from Bio import Seq    
OrigSeq = Seq.Seq(OriginalSeq_list[i])
translated_original = OrigSeq.translate()
```

Alternatively

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
OrigSeq = Seq(OriginalSeq_list[i])
translated_original = OrigSeq.translate()
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error: `AttributeError: type object 'Seq' has no attribute 'Seq'`

Comment: Ahh, got it to work. Should be `OrigSeq = Seq(OriginalSeq_list[i])`

Comment: Sorry, you imported Seq already from Bio.Seq, while I just imported Bio.Seq.  You should be able to use "Seq(OriginalSeq_list[i])".  I'll update my answer to clarify